# Are Parse local datastore queries are limited to 1000 objects?

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore

Queries in general are limited to returning 1000 objects at most according to the [Parse iOS Guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-constraints/iOS). This is true of other platforms too.

However then objects are stored locally there's no reason why this limit should apply. Does it apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the limit applies to all other platforms as well.

If you really need to get more than 1000 results in your query, see the following [Answer by a Parser](https://parse.com/questions/paging-through-more-than-10000-results).